# How to do this in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, replace

I Want to make this:
if my text is "AAA" still the same text, but if not is replace to "BBB", for example:

AAA CCC DDD AAA CCC DDD AAA CCC DDD
replace to:
AAA BBB BBB AAA BBB BBB AAA BBB BBB

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [SO] is not a code (or regex) writing service, you are expected to have tried and ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Is it important that the characters are in triplets, what happens if they are not. You don't say.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this LINQ approach using `String.Join` and `String.Split` is sufficient:

```
Dim str As String = "AAA CCC DDD AAA CCC DDD AAA CCC DDD"
Dim result = String.Join(" ", str.Split(" "c).Select(Function(s) If(s = "AAA", s, "BBB")))
```

Comment: Removed my answer as it was EXACTLY the same as yours with a few secs difference.

Comment: Tim Schmelter, no is this :/ I need to do this with a unknow text.

but dont is this: textbox1.text.replace("CCC", "BBB") I need a command equal to this, but no is this.
i need this >
if the text is not AAA, replace to BBB.

Thanks.